# How we place the image in Rectangle in canvas

Tags: android

Hi In canvas we have `drawrect()` method for  drawing rectangle. I now want to fill it with Image view. For this what can i do? Give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess its the fifth question related to the same topic from you today...

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
drawable.setBounds(myRect);
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Please! I gave you three times a link to a tutorial series where you can learn 2D drawing including collision detection from scratch, but you probably just read the first sentence... without reading you are not getting very far...

Comment: Faith But if we have already an image on the background and I want to put the overlay image what is the possible way to done this ?
I have tried this code but I cant get the image.